# Was Euler really the first who proposed the streamline integration principle?

Tags: integration

I am interested who first came up with line integration in a vector field to construct lines. So far I think ([based on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method)) it was Euler with his book: [*Institutionum calculi integralis*](http://books.google.de/books?id=Vg8OAAAAQAAJ). Do you know of any other prior publication to this matter?

**Edit:** A colleague just told me, that he have heard of flow visualizations already within the medieval age... but he cannot comment any further :(